# How to map a set<text> field of cassandra using spark Dataset to a POJO in java

Tags: apache-spark, collections, cassandra, datastax

I am having a set< text> field in my cassandra table and I am creating Apache sparks Dataset of the same table having some other fields as well. When i print the value of Dataset the values are getting printed but when I map the Dataset to a POJO then the field having set< text> type gives value null and rest of the fields gives their respective values.

the test_ids field in cassandra is of type set< text> and in java i am using HashSet< String > to represent it. If anyone can help then please do respond.

```
Dataset<Row> dsQ = spark1.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(props1).load();
    dsQ.show();

Dataset<Employee> res = dsQ.as(Encoders.bean(Employee.class));
    res.collectAsList().forEach(employee -> {
        System.out.println("POJO: " + employee);
});


//POJO Class
@Column("emp_branch")
private String empBranch;

@Column("epoch_hour")
private int epochHour;

@Column("test_ids")
private Set<String> testIds = new HashSet<String>();

public String getEmpBranch() {
    return empBranch;
}
public void setEmpBranch(String empBranch) {
    this.empBranch = empBranch;
}
public int getEpochHour() {
    return epochHour;
}
public void setEpochHour(int epochHour) {
    this.epochHour = epochHour;
}
public Set<String> getTestIds() {
    return testIds;
}
public void setTestIds(Set<String> testIds) {
    this.testIds = testIds;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StackOverflow [empBranch=" + empBranch + ", epochHour=" + epochHour + ", testIds=" + testIds + "]";
}
```

[Actual Result]
emp_branch=cs, epoch_hour=433064, test_ids=[ ]

[Expected Result]
emp_branch=cs, epoch_hour=433064, test_ids=['1234']

Comment: please show the definition of your POJO

Comment: I have added my POJO.

Comment: Can u help me out with this issue ..?

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee pojo should have something like this;

```
@Column("test_ids")
private Set<String> testIds= new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: I have added my pojo, also i don't think if annotations are creating a issue here. It is just that the set< text> in cassandra and Set< String> in java does not seem to be compatible with other.  Also in java set is an interface and we cannot instantiate it so i used HashSet but i am getting no result for test_ids.

Comment: Yes. Please check this documentation https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/creating/  
By default, the mapper tries to map each Java property to a case insensitive column of the same name. If you want to use a different name, or case-sensitive names, use the @Column annotation on the field.